# android open link in external browser

Tags: android, webview

I am trying to figure out ways to package few html with flash, and bundle it as android project.
Instead of creating webview and loading the webview

```
webView.loadUrl("file:///..");
```

is it possible to load the bundled file in native (external) browser on tablet?

Comment: Is there a specific reason you want to do this?

Comment: @sandalone you need reason to solve the issue or the reason solves the issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add browsable category in the intent.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.fromFile("file:////"));
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_BROWSABLE);
startActivity(intent);
```

**Note:** dont hard code the path use Evironment.getExternalEnvironment() to get path of external sdcard